# Need a better way to compare one column value to many column values in the same table row

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL 2017 datatable structured this way:

| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

For reporting purposes, I need a TSQL query to go through each row, get the value from column A, and compare that to each of the values in cols 1-3. If the value of col A is greater than the value of col [x], a counter should be iterated. When all comparisons for that row are complete, I record the counter's final value, then rinse and repeat for the next row.

Doing this process RBAR and cell-by-cell is not going to work. My actual table has 300+ rows, and 15 columns to which the initial value should be compared. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: @Austin A counter to track the number of times Col A was greater than Col [X] in the given row. For example (this is the way I'm doing it now, the way I want to change): in row 1, col A = 5. Is col A > col 1? No. Is col A > col 2? Yes; add 1 to the counter. And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN A > [1] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          CASE WHEN A > [2] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          CASE WHEN A > [3] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS counter
FROM yourTable;
```